# How to check the time difference between state change of a webelement using Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have a webelement with text "A". After sometime it will change to "B" based on a backend process. I want to write a tampermonkey script to check for the time difference between this state change and if it crosses some specific time say 30 mins then I need to trigger a desktop notification.

One glitch is for checking the state change I'm refreshing the page for every 5 minutes now. Does this cause any effect on my requirement ?

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Test State Change
// @version      0.1
// @author       Aravindh
// @include      https://www.google.com
// @grant        GM_notification
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
// ==/UserScript==


setTimeout(function()
{
  location.reload(true);
  var runStatus = document.getElementById("id").textContent;
  var expectedStatus = "running"
  var status = runStatus.localeCompare(expectedStatus);
  console.log(status);
   if(status > -1)
    {
        GM_notification ( {title: 'foo', text: '42', timeout: 60000 } );
    }
}, 600000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of Tampermonkey, so i don't know if that would affect it in some way, but this can be easily done in vanilla JavaSript:

First of, JavaScript is an Event-driven, language. Everything can be made to act and react to changes in the environment. So using `setTimeout` to see wether something has chaned is not the best approach.

Instead you install an event-listener or observer.
I can't really give too many details, as i'm a back-ender and not really familiar with the dom and there might be an easier solution. but in Essence:

```js
// create a Mutation observer (google for details, you'll find better info than i coud give you)
const observer = new MutationObserver(([{addedNodes, removedNodes}]) => /*add some callback function here*/)

// observe the element
observer.observe(document.getElementByID('yourElement'), {childList: true, /* observe childListChanges */})

// add the timer for the max amount of time (eg. 30min)
const timeLimit = 1.8e6
let currentTimeout = setTimeout(onExpire, timeLimit)

// the callback when the timer expires
function onExpire () {
  // do something
}
```

Now every time the cildList of that elemnt changes, your callback will be called.
A callback could look something like this:

```js
function callBack (mutations) {
  // `target` is the element, added/removedNodes is the observed change
  for (const {target, addedNodes, removedNodes} of mutations) {
    // check if the change you are looking for occured
    if (/*desired change occured*/) {
      // kill the old timeout
      clearTimeout(currentTimeout /* the timeout from above */)
      // start a new timeout
      currentTimeout = setTimeout(onExpire, timeLimit/* same params as before */)
    }
  }
}
```